# Failed to execute goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:1.5.7.RELEASE e: Could not exec java: Application finished with exit code: 1

Tags: eclipse, maven, spring-mvc

Error display when i press Ctrl+c in cmd

```
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE

[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:1.5.7.RELEASE:run (default-cli) on project beeqe: Could not exec java: Application finished with exit code: 1 -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin 5.7.RELEASE:run (default-cli) on project beequote: Could not exec java
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:213)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:154)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:146)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:309)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:194)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:107)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:993)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:345)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:191)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.maven.wrapper.BootstrapMainStarter.start(BootstrapMainStarter.java:39)
    at org.apache.maven.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:122)
    at org.apache.maven.wrapper.MavenWrapperMain.main(MavenWrapperMain.java:50)
```

Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Could not exec java
        at org.springframework.boot.maven.RunMojo.runWithForkedJvm(RunMojo.java:82)
        at org.springframework.boot.maven.AbstractRunMojo.doRunWithForkedJvm(AbstractRunMojo.java:279)
        at org.springframework.boot.maven.AbstractRunMojo.run(AbstractRunMojo.java:245)
        at org.springframework.boot.maven.AbstractRunMojo.execute(AbstractRunMojo.java:181)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
        ... 27 more

```
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Application finished with exit code: 1
    at org.springframework.boot.maven.RunMojo.runWithForkedJvm(RunMojo.java:78)
    ... 32 more
[ERROR]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1]
```

http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException

Comment: when i run maven project then display:  Application 'beequote' is running! Access URLs:
  Local:          http://localhost:8080
  External:       http://192.168.43.205:8080
  Profile(s):     [swagger, dev] ----------------   but in browser can't display anything and then i press Ctrl+c in browser then diaplay above error so help me please...

Comment: Ok, please add that information to the question.

Comment: That is not code, that is error in spring + maven project

Comment: Post your pom.xml and the mvn command run at the command line or the actions you carry out in eclipse. There is insufficient information presented in your question to provide the necessary context for people to help you.

Answer (score 0):

The question is quite old but I'll share my answer in case someone stumbles upon this. I had exact same problem and the cause was incorrect configuration of logback in `logback-spring.xml`.

If you're using logback (it's used by default in Spring Boot), try commenting the whole configuration out and un-comment it step by step. It sounds tedious but that's what worked for me.

To show some examples of my misconfiguration:

```xml
<logger name="org.apache.camel.component.file" level="error"additivity="false">
```

is supposed to be

```xml
<logger name="org.apache.camel.component.file" level="error" additivity="false">
```

```xml
    <appender name="..." class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        ...

        <rollingPolicy
                class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.FixedWindowRollingPolicy">
            ...
            <triggeringPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy">
                <maxFileSize>10MB</maxFileSize>
            </triggeringPolicy>
        </rollingPolicy>

    </appender>
```

is supposed to be

```xml
    <appender name="..." class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        ...

        <rollingPolicy
                class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.FixedWindowRollingPolicy">
            ...

        </rollingPolicy>

        <triggeringPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy">
            <maxFileSize>10MB</maxFileSize>
        </triggeringPolicy>

    </appender>
```